# calling php script within php with return value

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get a return value from a script which returns per echo "complete" or "error". First I tought I could get this working with the php function `file_get_contents`, but it returns my whole script, not only the things I am printing in the script. Then I believed in the `cURL` method, but it can't get it working....

The script which is called:

```
<?php 
include("config.php");
print "complete";
?>
```

the script with my curl:

```
$url="caller.php";
$ch = curl_init(); //initialize curl handle
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); //set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); //return as a variable
$response = curl_exec($ch); //run the whole process and return the response
curl_close($ch); //close the curl handle

echo "test". $response."|";
```

Why isn't this working? And how can I get it working?! FILE Method?

Comment: shouldn't the url be an actual url? like `file:///caller.php`

Comment: just tried it, it doesn't work with a `file://` url, this echoes the complete file content without executing the php code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to capture the echoed values of an included script, you can use output buffering:

```
<?php
ob_start();    // start output buffering
include("caller.php");
$returned_value = ob_get_contents();    // get contents from the buffer
ob_end_clean();    // stop output buffering
?>
```

Comment: no the script isnt included, i need to give some get/post variables to it.the include is only in the first script to see if i get the whole script returned...

Comment: @user1010775 If the script is located on the same server, all `GET` and `POST` variables are already available in any included script.

Comment: this doesn't work, the complete file content is echoed, the php in it is not executed.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider The OP was using `file_get_contents`, not `include`.

Comment: Ignore my comment, I ran my test against the wrong file, this works. My bad.

Comment: its now working also for me, i need to print the $retruned_value after the ob_end_clean. THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need a valid http (or other protocol) with a full URL to the script for curl to work 
e.g. **http://localhost/caller.php**

Or try `jeroen`'s solution and get the output of the script.

Comment: my http adress which i can call in the browser, or file://completepath isnt working!

Answer (score 0):

In the script to be called, make sure "<?php" start from the first line, first character. And, remove the "?>" away.

```
<?php
//this is 'to-be-called.php'
include("config.php");
echo "complete";
```

Now call it this way:

```
<?php
//this is 'caller.php'
//should it come with full url?
$Url      = "http://localhost/path/to-be-called.php"; 
$Handle   = curl_init($Url);
$Response = curl_exec($Handle);
curl_close($Handle);

echo $Response;
```

Or take Jeroen's answer, it's the best way for calling on the same server! If you need to pass in parameters in POST/GET, tell 'caller.php' to save these values in global variables, then tell 'to-be-called.php' to get from these global ones.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite `caller.php` in a way that fills a variable instead of echoing text, ideally put it in a function that returns that variable. Everything else is a dirty hack, prone to error and a source for performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `php` cgi to run script and get content. Use `shell_exec`